Writing a test script using Forge solidity scripting. Forge build error
I have a simple token and liquidity pool factory contract written in Solidity.
As I was writing a test script (solidity scripting) using foundry forge, I had a problem.

factory is an object of BullshotFactory contract. Any idea on those erros?
Kindly let me know what you need to check more.

Post the code .

Switch RHS and LHS in line 109
BullshotFactory.TokenState.TRADING=factory.tokens(tokenAddress)

In line 122
_createLiquidityPool() has limited visibility or doesn't exist .
Different types of visibilty modifiers
public -    Can access the function from any contract or EOA
private-    Can access the function only from the current contract
internal-   Can access the function only from derived contract
external-   Can access the function only from an external contract 
            or EOA 


BullshotFactory.TokenState.TRADING = factory.tokens(tokenAddress);
This code also has a same issue.
